pgfplotstable: font color of a row
I want to create a pgfplotstable with a list of x and y coordinates. Some rows should have a font color.



Here is my actual code:
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{noto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} % math in serif but noto
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % math in default serif math font

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel} % German date formats

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[inner sep=0pt, scale=0.8] {
                    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
                    col sep = &, row sep =  \\, 
                    columns/v/.style={column type=l|, string type, column name={},
                        postproc cell content/.append style={
                            /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={$\pmb}{$},
                        },
                    },
                    columns/x1/.style={column name={X},fixed, fixed zerofill=true,precision=2, dec sep align},
                    columns/x2/.style={column name={Y},fixed, fixed zerofill=true,precision=2, dec sep align},
                    every head row/.style={after row=\hline},  
                    ]{
                        v & x1 & x2 \\
                        {P}_1 & 43.46 & 28.77 \\
                        {P}_{1,2} & 70.68 & 29.79 \\
                        {P}_{2,1} & 85.23 & 2.13 \\
                        {P}_2 & 84.36 & 26.06 \\
                        {P}_{2,2} & 83.85 & 40.01 \\
                        {P}_{3,1} & 62.15 & 49.34 \\
                        {P}_3 & 32.94 & 52.91 \\
                        {P}_{3,2} & 11.95 & 32.81 \\
                        {P}_{4,1} & 0.02 & 4.73 \\
                        {P}_4 & 18.63 & 2.07 \\
                        {P}_{4,2} & 32.03 & 0.15 \\
                        {P}_{1,1} & 21.27 & 27.93 \\
                        {P}_1 & 43.46 & 28.77 \\
                    } 
                };
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}




This is the result I get:




This is the result, I want:




I was thinking of using the  /pgfplots/table/every nth row={integer[shift]}{options} and something like  postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\textcolor{red}{##1}}. But I was not able to find a working solution.
Can you please support?
Thank you.
Kind regards, Philipp

Update
I found a code snipped that allows to color one cell content: pgfplotstable: how can I change the color of a cell's content while maintaining the style?
every row 1 column 0/.append style={
postproc cell content/.append code={%
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\myTmpVal}%
\pgfkeysalso{my special cell/.expand once={\myTmpVal}}%
},},

Proposal, that does not work:
\foreach \rowidx in {1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11}{
    every row \rowidx column 0/.append style={
        postproc cell content/.append code={%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\myTmpVal}%
            \pgfkeysalso{my special cell/.expand once={\myTmpVal}}%
        },
    },
}%


Unrelated to your question, but you don't need \usepackage{amsmath}, beamer will load it automatically. And if your tex distribution is up-to-date, you also don't need \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}, that has been the default since a couple of years.

Hello samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz,
Thank you for the hint.

Any solution for the problem, how to define font colors for specific rows?
Thank you.

Why did you choose pgfplotstable over other Latex tables? At least one table package provides coloration.

Hello MS-SPO, Which package do you suggest? Actually, I don't have a reason for choosing pgfplotstable. On the other hand, I wonder, that it is not possible with pgfplotstable.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, @MS-SPO,
I found a code snippet, that colors at least one cell. Next step would be to iterate over all columns. Here is the snipped:
 every row 4 column 1/.append style={
 postproc cell content/.append style={
 my special cell/.expanded={%
 \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
 },
 },
 },```

After a lot of reading and trial and error, I found a solution that colors certain lines:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\pgfplotstableset{my special cell/.style={@cell content=\color{red}#1}}
\pgfplotstableset{color row/.style=
    {
        postproc cell content/.append code={
            \count0=\pgfplotstablerow
            \advance\count0 by0
            \ifnum\count0=#1
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\myTmpVal}%
            \pgfkeysalso{my special cell/.expand once={\myTmpVal}}%
            \fi},     
        },      
        }

\begin{document}

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep = &, row sep =  \\, 
    columns/v/.style={column type=l|, string type, column name={}},
    columns/x1/.style={fixed, fixed zerofill=true,precision=2, dec sep align},
    columns/x2/.style={fixed, fixed zerofill=true,precision=2, dec sep align},
    every head row/.style={after row=\hline}, 
    color row/.list={1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11},
    ]{
        v & x1 & x2 \\
        $\pmb{P}_1$ & 43.46 & 28.77 \\
        $\pmb{P}_{1,2}$ & 70.68 & 29.79 \\
        $\pmb{P}_{2,1}$ & 85.23 & 2.13 \\
        $\pmb{P}_2$ & 84.36 & 26.06 \\
        $\pmb{P}_{2,2}$ & 83.85 & 40.01 \\
        $\pmb{P}_{3,1}$ & 62.15 & 49.34 \\
        $\pmb{P}_3$ & 32.94 & 52.91 \\
        $\pmb{P}_{3,2}$ & 11.95 & 32.81 \\
        $\pmb{P}_{4,1}$ & 0.02 & 4.73 \\
        $\pmb{P}_4$ & 18.63 & 2.07 \\
        $\pmb{P}_{4,2}$ & 32.03 & 0.15 \\
        $\pmb{P}_{1,1}$ & 21.27 & 27.93 \\
        $\pmb{P}_1$ & 43.46 & 28.77 \\
    }
    
\end{document}


The main posts that led to the answer where:

pgfplotstable: how can I change the color of a cell's content while maintaining the style?
pgfplotstable: Highlight rows of a numeric sequence



I have to admit, I do not know why it works...


Here is the desired output:




Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and @Celdor for the alternative solutions.

Better use @Celdor's answer. Unlike mine, it works with siunitx in order to get proper alignment of the values in the table

You could use the tabularray package for your table:
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} 

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\intmodnn\int_mod:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tblr}{
              colspec={Q[mode=imath]|Q[halign=r]|Q[halign=r]},
              cell{1}{1}={mode=text},
              row{1}={halign=c},
              cell{2-Z}{1-Z}={preto={%
                \ifnum\intmodnn{\therownum}{3}<2
                  \color{red}%
                \fi
              }}
            }
              v & x1 & x2 \\
              \hline
              {P}_1 & 43.46 & 28.77 \\
              {P}_{1,2} & 70.68 & 29.79 \\
              {P}_{2,1} & 85.23 & 2.13 \\
              {P}_2 & 84.36 & 26.06 \\
              {P}_{2,2} & 83.85 & 40.01 \\
              {P}_{3,1} & 62.15 & 49.34 \\
              {P}_3 & 32.94 & 52.91 \\
              {P}_{3,2} & 11.95 & 32.81 \\
              {P}_{4,1} & 0.02 & 4.73 \\
              {P}_4 & 18.63 & 2.07 \\
              {P}_{4,2} & 32.03 & 0.15 \\
              {P}_{1,1} & 21.27 & 27.93 \\
              {P}_1 & 43.46 & 28.77 \\
            \end{tblr}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} 

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\intmodnn\int_mod:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tblr}{
              colspec={Q[mode=imath]|Q[halign=r]|Q[halign=r]},
              cell{1}{1}={mode=text},
              row{1}={halign=c},
              cell{2-Z}{1-Z}={preto={%
                \ifnum\intmodnn{\therownum}{3}<2
                  \color{red}%
                \fi
              }}
            }
              v & x1 & x2 \\
              \hline
              {P}_1 & 43.46 & 28.77 \\
              {P}_{1,2} & 70.68 & 29.79 \\
              {P}_{2,1} & 85.23 & 2.13 \\
              {P}_2 & 84.36 & 26.06 \\
              {P}_{2,2} & 83.85 & 40.01 \\
              {P}_{3,1} & 62.15 & 49.34 \\
              {P}_3 & 32.94 & 52.91 \\
              {P}_{3,2} & 11.95 & 32.81 \\
              {P}_{4,1} & 0.02 & 4.73 \\
              {P}_4 & 18.63 & 2.07 \\
              {P}_{4,2} & 32.03 & 0.15 \\
              {P}_{1,1} & 21.27 & 27.93 \\
              {P}_1 & 43.46 & 28.77 \\
            \end{tblr}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}



Hello together,
I found a code snipped, that allows to color a single cell:
pgfplotstable: how can I change the color of a cell's content while maintaining the style?
Next step would be to iterate over a number of cells.

does anyone know, how to iterate in \pgfplotstabletypeset over a list of row indices? I posted a proposal in the main question, that does not work. ...

Alternatively to samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's answer, you can define a custom repetitive multiple row selector. Add this snippet to your preamble
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{everythirdtwo}{
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {2} {3}
        {\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
        {\clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

and then you can use this selector with row, column, and even line specifications, e.g. row[everythirdtwo].
Additionally, since your table contains numeric data, I'd also recommend siunitx package for a better number formatting.
Here's code:
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169,svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{noto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} % math in serif but noto
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % math in default serif math font
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector { everythirdtwo } {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {2} {3}
        {\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
        {\clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec = {
                Q[l,mode=math]
                *2{S[table-format=2.2]}
            },
            rows = {
                fg=Red,
                rowsep=1pt,
            },
            row{everythirdtwo} = {fg=Black},   % custom selector
            row{1} = {
                fg=Black,
                halign=c,
                guard,
                mode=text,
            },
            hline{everythirdtwo} = {wd=0.05pt},   % custom selector
            hline{1-2} = {wd=0pt},
        }
        \toprule
        v & x1 & x2 \\
        \midrule
        P_{1} & 43.46 & 28.77 \\
        P_{1,2} & 70.68 & 29.79 \\
        P_{2,1} & 85.23 & 2.13 \\
        P_{2} & 84.36 & 26.06 \\
        P_{2,2} & 83.85 & 40.01 \\
        P_{3,1} & 62.15 & 49.34 \\
        P_{3} & 32.94 & 52.91 \\
        P_{3,2} & 11.95 & 32.81 \\
        P_{4,1} & 0.02 & 4.73 \\
        P_{4} & 18.63 & 2.07 \\
        P_{4,2} & 32.03 & 0.15 \\
        P_{1,1} & 21.27 & 27.93 \\
        P_1 & 43.46 & 28.77 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Nice solution! Thanks for sharing! Nice that it works with siunitx!
